# Check for a especific value inside a string

Tags: java, android, string, bluetooth

**UPDATED**

In my app, I have a continuos communication with a PCB via bluetooth. This communication is made by HEX Strings.

The string format is like this:

```
2b(thread init), 05(write command), 09(bytes), 04(variable bytes), 5af2ff1f(memory location), 04a0bcf1(variable value), 7e(checksum)
```

The function of this Hex string is to access to a concrete memory location of the PCB and write a value.

To do it easier, lets suppouse that the Hex string is:

```
hex_string= 2B05A82BF1
```

This string, before sending it via bluetooth, I convert it to a Byte[]. What I need is to create a function that checks all the strings I send.

What I must look for, is for any "2B" byte inside the string. This is because the PCB reads the "2b" as a "init thread" value and if there is any "2b" inside the string, the PCB would read it as the init of another thread and the string wouldn't be sent entirely.

I don't know if is easier to check this with the Hex String, or after converting it to Byte[].

The function would be to disscard the first "2b" of the string and check if there is another "2b" inside the string, and if it is, duplicate it, resulting this.

```
before: hex_string= 2B05A82BF1
after: hex_string= 2B05A82B2BF1
```

This way the PCB understands that that "2b" is not a init thread value.

What I want to do is a function that checks all string for containing "2b" value inside of it. But i don't know if it's better to do this with the Hex string, when converted to byte[]... or when... and how to do it.

Comment: You just want to check if the string contain some values. Maybe using substring() is enough ?

Comment: I have updated the question with a more detalied explanation

Comment: if im not wrong, u get a string something like 2BXXXXXX2BXXXX and u want it to change like 2BXXXXXX2B2BXXXX

Comment: @Amith GC, that's it! i don't care if is in string format or byte[] format. What I need is just that, a function that checks for anoter "2b" inside of it and if there is, duplicate it.

Comment: When you transform the String into bytes... are you sending 2B (43 in decimal) or the values of the characters '2' and 'B'? I ask it because if you send '2b02b0' and you are sending the hex numbers, the second 2b is not 43, but 02 (2) and b0 (-80)

Comment: @Pablo Lozano I send the "2B" as a 43 in decimal

Comment: @Amith GC, I'm trying it in my code, but I asked you one more thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you are looking for? not sure...

> Input: 2BXX09XX2BYYYY Output: 2BXX0AXX2B2BYYYY

```
public class Temp {

    public static void main (String args[]) {
        String input = convertSting("2BXX09XX2BYYYY");
        input = replaceSize(input, "0A");

        System.out.println(input);
    }

    private static String replaceSize(String input, String newSizeVal) {
        int sizePosition = 4;
        return input.substring(0, sizePosition) + newSizeVal + input.substring(sizePosition + newSizeVal.length(), input.length());
    }

    public static String convertSting (String input) {
        String findString = "2B";

        int firstIndex = input.indexOf(findString) + findString.length();
        return input.substring(0, firstIndex) + input.substring(firstIndex, input.length()).replace(findString, "2B2B");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Amith GC, I'll try it right now. just one more thing. Besides doing this, the input string `2BXX09XX2BYYYY` would result in this `2BXX09XX2B2BYYYY`. The "09" value is the number of bytes of the entire string, so when adding the additional "2B", i should change that "09" to a "0A" to indicate the new length of the string. Could you add this too, to your example?

Comment: The 09 is the length of the string, it is always the same. The string's first values are always the same, and the last values are whose change. So we can't do it the way you check the 2B, because may be another 09 inside of it indicating a value. So, if the string contains a "2b" and we duplicate it, we must now change the "09" for a "0A"

Comment: look at my updated answer... for Input: 2BXX09XX2BYYYY Output: 2BXX0AXX2B2BYYYY

Comment: Of course, just let me try it on my code ;). Just for complete the function, could you add a conditional to check this: If there is a 2B inside the string, it does all this stuff, but if there isn't it mantains the string

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{       
 String str = "2B05A82BF1";
 String strNew = "";
 if (str.contains("2B")) 
{

strNew = str.replaceFirst("2B", "");
        }

  int index = 0;
   if (strNew.contains("2B")) 
{

index = strNew.indexOf("2B");
        }

    strNew = str.substring(0, index + 4);
            strNew = strNew + "2B" + str.substring(index + 4);
            System.out.println(strNew);
```

String tempStr = strNew.substring(2, 4);

```
    int i= Integer.parseInt(tempStr);
    //System.out.println(i);
    i=i+1;
    if(i<10)
    {
        strNew=strNew.replace(tempStr, "0"+ String.valueOf(i));
    }
    else
    {
        strNew=strNew.replace(tempStr, String.valueOf(i));
    }


    System.out.println(strNew);

        }
```

Comment: Good, you posted a similar solution but adding the if condition to check if there is any "2b" inside of it, or not. How would you change, lets say, from the string `2B05A82BF1`, the `05` supposing that it is the string's byte length, and when getting the resulting string with the duplicated "2b" `2B06A82B2BF1` now the byte length would be `06`, so this must be changed too.

Answer (score 1):

If you are taking the string and converting every pair of chars in the related number in one byte (for example `2b0a10` would be transform in `[43, 10, 16]`), I think it would be easier to check the byte array than the String one: you just need to search the number 43 and insert another one.
 I'd use an `ArrayList` to add every byte value, inserting the value 43 (0X2B) twice every time I find one, and then putting the values into a plain `array`.

Checking the String is more complex because you have to take into account that 2b02b0 is actually 2b, 02, b0, there is no '2b' value there.

Example:

```
public class Example {

    public static byte[] parseOutput(byte[] output) {
        ArrayList<Byte> aux= new ArrayList<Byte>();
        aux.add(output[0]); //we know the first value is 2b
        for (int i=1;i< output.length;i++) {
            aux.add(output[i]);
            if (output[i]==0x2b) {
                aux.add(output[i]); //added twice
            }
        }
        //we cannot use toArray because autoboxing does not work 
        byte[] result= new byte[aux.size()];
        for (int i=1;i< aux.size();i++) {
            result[i]=aux.get(i);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        byte[] b={43,11,11,43,15};

        byte[] result=parseOutput(b);
        for (byte data: result) {
            System.out.print(Integer.toHexString(data)+" "); // shows "0 b b 2b 2b f" 
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Considering that I have a function called "hexToByte" that converts the Hex string into a byte[]. How would you do the function that you are proposing?

Comment: Instead the hexToByte I've hardcoded a byte array b, but here you have it

Comment: Although I consider this method more effective rather than manage strings, I'll implement @Amith GC's method because it fits better with the structure of my code, anyway i'll take your method into account for future modifications.

Answer (score 0):

well, its your call when to check for the '2B'. Figure out where you can actually do something after finding a '2B'. If u decide to check for '2b' in java you can do so by

```
String result = "2B0509045AF2FF1F04A0BCF17E";
if(result.contains("2B"))
{
    //do something
}
else
{
    //do something else
}
```