# Function that checks for a value inside a string

Tags: java, android, string, multithreading, bluetooth

I'm developing an app that comunicates via bluetooth with a PCB. I send from the app to the PCB HEX strings like this:

```
hex_string = 2b0509045af2ff1f5230a9072b
```

Well, in this string these values are always the same `2b050904`, and these others represent `5af2ff1f` memory location, `5230a907` variable value and `2b` checksum.

The `2b` at the start represents the `thread init`, so basically what I need is to check for other `2b` inside the string, because if there is another, the PCB will understand it as an another thread init and will split the entire string.

So the steps are:

```
* Disregarding the 2b at the start, check for another 2b inside the string, and if it is,
  duplicate it, so the PCB understands it this way.
* Afther duplicating the 2b, change the 09 in the non variable part of the string, 
  that indicates the string's byte length, with a 0a.
```

After a discussion in this thread: [Check for a especific value inside a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18846485/check-for-a-especific-value-inside-a-string)

This is the function that I'm using to achieve this:

```
public static String manage2b (String s) {
    String sNew = null;
    String input = null;

    if (s.contains("2b")) {
        sNew = s.replaceFirst("2b", "");
    }
    if (sNew.contains("2b")) {
        input = convertString(s);
        input = replaceSize(input, "0a");
    }
    else {
        input = s;
    }
    return input;
}
/**Changes the 09 for 0a as the string's byte length if there is a duplicated "2b"*/
private static String replaceSize (String input, String newSizeVal) {
    int sizePosition = 4;
    return input.substring(0, sizePosition) + newSizeVal + input.substring(sizePosition + newSizeVal.length(), input.length());
}
/**Duplicates the "2b" if there is another inside the string*/
public static String convertString (String input) {
    String find2b = "2B";

    int firstIndex = input.indexOf(find2b) + find2b.length();
    return input.substring(0, firstIndex) + input.substring(firstIndex, input.length()).replace(find2b, "2B2B");
}
```

I've checked the function with the debugger, and with a string very similar to the example's one, it makes right the change from `09` to `0a`, but it doesn't duplicate the `2b`. So, I think that in the step of doing this, maybe I declared something wrong, or I'm making a mistake somewhere.

Comment: Could it simply be because of case sensitivity? In the convertString you are finding 2B instead of 2b

Comment: @Wouter Wow, does it really treat uppercase different than the lowercase??

Answer (score 0):

Yes... "2b" is different from "2B"... change it... I think it will work after that... ( I am not allowed to comment.. sorry..)

Comment: Changed. Still must to check it, will comment when checked... but I've just tryed it without the debbuger and still doesn't work. When I can debbug it, I will post

Comment: It works... u have to change "2B" to "2b" in your convertString() function as well...

Answer (score 0):

It seems correct if String doens't look for case match.

Answer (score 0):

also, do you have to check for just one single recurring "2b" or might there be several?
while(s.contains("2b") || s.contains("2B"))

could help you there.

as for the case sensitivity:

org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP", "gHi");

can help you there, so:

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
...

while ( StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(s, "2b")) ...

should fix that.

Comment: For the momment, I've only getted one "2b" inside of the string, but could be more... For the case sensitivity, I just changed "2B" for "2b" and I think doing this is enought